# Stop addEventListener in Angular 6

Tags: spring-boot, rxjs, addeventlistener, angular6, server-sent-events

I have the below code in Angular component

```
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    source:any;
    connect(dateValue){  
        this.source = new 
        EventSource('http://localhost:8080/api/schedbydate?mydate='+dateValue);

        this.source.addEventListener('datarec', datarec => {
            let schedule: Notification;
            this.schedule = JSON.parse(datarex.data);
        }, false);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._erdayService.getErday().subscribe((erday) => {
            this._date = erday.text();
            this._erdayService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {        
                this._date = message;
                this.connect(this._date);}     
           , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR: SELECTED DAY'); });}
        , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR:getSchedulesByDate()'); });
     }

   ngOnDestroy() {
       this.source.removeEventListener('message', this.message, false); 
       //this line doesn't work because I can't access enter variable here!
        console.log("Server stopped schedule");
   }
}
```

The issue is the ***this._date*** is initially loaded ***erday*** and UI view is according to ***erday***. Now when I change the ***this._date*** to ***message***, the UI view gets changed.
But still the ***erday*** data is shown in UI and the UI view fluctuates between  ***erday*** & ***message*** and I'm not able to stop the ***this.source.addEventListener()***.

I tried to destroy in ***ngOnDestroy()***,but it is not working.
I even tried ***this.source.close();***.

Can someone help to know how to stop the listener created before calling another listener on same source ?

Comment: I think this is not related to Angular, just see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Not sure I get what you want : 
- How much message does your `this._erdayService.getErday()` emit ?
- What is the purpose of subscribing to EventSource if you want to replace the date by erday ?

Comment: Use case:  
I have a table for which the data comes from MySql DB, and I opened a ***SSEemiiter*** Stream using Spring boot, which has a Select query, with _date=?_ in _WHERE_ clause, to which Angular listens.

The default date should be event date.  
But I have a date picker, which will changed to old date, to see the old dates data, which is be constant.  

So the data for event day only changes, but not the old dates.  
But currently the code above is fluctuates, which is not getting closed.  

I hope you understood my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subscribe to 2 data sources that emits continuously : 
- The first being `this._erdayService.currentMessage`
- The second is this.source (when you trigger this.connect())

So this._date will change continuously. So you have to decide which data source you want to keep.

**Case 1: You want to keep this.source as your data provider:**

```
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    source:any;
    sourceListenerSubscription$ : Observable<any>;
    connect(dateValue){  
        this.source = new 
        EventSource('http://localhost:8080/api/schedbydate?mydate='+dateValue);
        this.sourceSubscription$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.source, 'datarec').subscribe( datarec => {
            let schedule: Notification;
            this.schedule = JSON.parse(datarex.data);
        }, false);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._erdayService.getErday().subscribe((erday) => {
            this._date = erday.text();
            // take only one erday message, then listen to your spring server
            this._erdayService.currentMessage.take(1).subscribe(message => {        
                this._date = message;
                this.connect(this._date);}     
           , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR: SELECTED DAY'); });}
        , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR:getSchedulesByDate()'); });
     }

   ngOnDestroy() {
       this.source.removeEventListener('message', this.message, false); 
       //this line doesn't work because I can't access enter variable here!
        console.log("Server stopped schedule");
   }
}
```

**Case 2: You want to keep erday as your data provider:**

```
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    source:any;
    sourceListenerSubscription$ : Observable<any>;
    connect(dateValue){  
        this.source = new 
        EventSource('http://localhost:8080/api/schedbydate?mydate='+dateValue);
        // take date once from spring server, and keep erday as data source
        this.sourceSubscription$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.source, 'datarec').take(1).subscribe( datarec => {
            let schedule: Notification;
            this.schedule = JSON.parse(datarex.data);
        }, false);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._erdayService.getErday().subscribe((erday) => {
            this._date = erday.text();
            this._erdayService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {        
                this._date = message;
                this.connect(this._date);}     
           , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR: SELECTED DAY'); });}
        , (error) => { console.error('SERVER ERROR:getSchedulesByDate()'); });
     }

   ngOnDestroy() {
       this.source.removeEventListener('message', this.message, false); 
       //this line doesn't work because I can't access enter variable here!
        console.log("Server stopped schedule");
   }
}
```

Comment: sourceListener$, how should I declare it ?

Comment: I'm getting `this.sourceListener$.unsubscribe();` as error. What to be corrected  ?

Comment: Still `this.sourceSubscription$.unsubscribe();` as error, after changing to `sourceSubscription$ : Observable<any>;` and `datarex.data` to `datarec.data`, I think `unscubcribe` is not a part of `Observerable`. Can you revalidate your code ?

Comment: You can in fact unsubscribe from a subscription. Here's an example :

`const source = Observable.interval(200);
let subscription = source.subscribe( x=> console.log(x))

Observable.timer(2000).subscribe( _=> subscription.unsubscribe())`

But in your case, I think there's a race condition, and the unsubscribe happens before the subscription. 
Updating the code for 2 scenarios.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. They worked. Thanks for your suggesting code many times.